# Laravel pusher-php-server sends unicode instead of cyrillic symbols

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, unicode, pusher

I have the Laravel API project with realtime chat functionality.

I am using

```
"beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.13",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "7.0"
```

So, I have an event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Http\Resources\Messenger\WebsocketResource;
use App\Models\Messages;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class MessagePushNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithSockets;
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public Messages $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Messages $message, $user)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return (new WebsocketResource($this->message))->toArray(request());
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): Channel|array
    {
        Log::channel('websockets')->debug('Broadcasting event: MyWebSocketEvent', [
            'payload' => $this->message
        ]);

        return new Channel('chatMessage');
    }

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'chatMessage';
    }
}
```

and Resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Messenger;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class WebsocketResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request): array|\JsonSerializable|Arrayable
    {
        $message = $this->text;
        $senderId = $this->sender_id;
        $createdAt = $this->created_at->toDateTimeString();

        Log::info('WebsocketResource', [
            'message' => $message,
            'sender_id' => $senderId,
            'message_created_at' => $createdAt,
        ]);

        return [
            'message' => $message,
            'sender_id' => $senderId,
            'message_created_at' => $createdAt,
        ];
    }
}
```

after message has created with help of rest, Message observer trigger event, and in websocket channel I am getting response with channel, event and data, and if I use latin in my message it is fine, but when I am trying to send cyrrilic symbols it shows a unicode. I have log in my resource, and message at that place is fine, so it is not related to database config or something.

[Cyrillic symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TufHI.png)
[Latin symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAmH2.png)

I searched accross the internet, but still can not find a solution, please help. I need to get cyrillic symbols in response.